# Is it possible to log to different location for different kind of logs using log4go?

Tags: logging, go

I noticed `log4go` has the `filter` mechanism. But it's based on `level`. That is, logs above certain level goes to certain `filter`. What I want to achieve is, for example, we have two types of logs, `sheep` and `goat`,  each with all the levels `DEBUG`, `INFO` etc, log of type `sheep` go to `sheep.log`, log of type `goat` goes to `goat.log`. Is it possible using log4go?

Comment: It is very frequently used mechanism that you want to use. Usually all widly used log package have this functionality. If could have been more useful if would have provided github url of the package that you are using and may be some code explaining how you are using it.

Comment: @MayankPatel I'm going to checkout logrus https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, since the [`Filter` struct](https://github.com/alecthomas/log4go/blob/1bcc57d8a00d336186452f94c1514934616bb8f4/log4go.go#L124-L129) which is set by [`AddFilter(name string, lvl Level, writer LogWriter)`](https://github.com/alecthomas/log4go/blob/1bcc57d8a00d336186452f94c1514934616bb8f4/log4go.go#L174-L180) only filters on the log level, without consideration of "type".

You would have to extend that filter in order to add the "type".